# Like and Unlike Button in React

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, react-hooks, state, togglebutton

I wanted to implement a like/unlike button in each post. When I click 'like,' it does update in my rails backend, and it does toggle from 'like' to 'unlike.' However, after I go to a different post and return to that post, the 'unlike' button is back to 'like.'

```
const [postLikes, setPostLikes] = useState(0);
    const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false);
    const params = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`/posts/${post.id}/likes`)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => setPostLikes(data))
    }, [post.id])
```

```
const handleLike = () => {
        fetch(`/posts/${post.id}/likes`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(setLiked(postLikes))
        .catch(error => {
            setErrors(error)
        })
    }

    const handleUnlike = () => {
        fetch(`/posts/${post.id}/likes/${params.id}`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(setLiked(postLikes))
        .catch(error => {
            setErrors(error)
        })
    }
```

```
<div className="box-2">
                <h1>{post.title}</h1>
                <h5>{post.creator.username}</h5>
                <p>{post.content}</p>
                {liked ? (
                    <button className="edit-btn" onClick={handleUnlike}>Unlike: {postLikes.length}</button>
                ):(
                    <button className="edit-btn" onClick={handleLike}>like: {postLikes.length}</button>
                )}
                <button className="edit-btn" onClick={openComment}>Comments</button>
                {user && user.username === post.creator?.username && (
                    <>
                    <button className="edit-btn"><Link to={`/posts/${post.id}/edit`}>Edit</Link></button>
                    <button className="edit-btn" onClick={onDeletePost}>Delete</button>
                    </>
                )}
            </div>
```

I am new to coding so this might be an easy fix, I am just not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should update the liked state based on whether the user's ID is found in the fetched likes data. This could be done using the some method on the data array to check if the user has already liked the post Like this.

```
const [postLikes, setPostLikes] = useState(0);
const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false);
const params = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
fetch(`/posts/${post.id}/likes`)
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(data => {
    setPostLikes(data);
    // Check if the user has liked this post
    setLiked(data.some(like => like.user_id === currentUser.id)); 
// Adjust this based on your data structure
})}, [post.id, currentUser.id]);


const handleLike = () => {
fetch(`/posts/${post.id}/likes`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
})
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(data => {
    setPostLikes(data);
   // setLiked State to true if response is 200
    setLiked(true);
})
.catch(error => {
    setErrors(error)
});
}

   const handleUnlike = () => {
    fetch(`/posts/${post.id}/likes/${params.id}`, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    })
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
        setPostLikes(data); //setLiked State to false if response is 200
        setLiked(false);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        setErrors(error)
    });
}
```